# Create Constraint To Ensure Date Range Is Within Another Date Range

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints, referential-integrity

I am trying to create a scheduling application, and part of it requires the date range of a row to be within the date range of a row in another table, which it is referencing via a foreign key.

Note: This is Postgres.

The schema is as follows:

```
table_1:
id Serial
name Varchar
date_range DATERANGE
```

```
table_2:
id Serial
name Varchar
date_range DATERANGE
table_1_id - Foreign Key, this references the id of a record in table 1.
```

I am trying to figure out how to write a check constraint that enforces the rule that the `date_range` in `table_2` has to be within the `date_range` of `table_1`.

Comment: Search for exclusion constraints; there were several good answers on this site alone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no really good way to do this. The only option I can think of is to hold a redundant copy of `table_1`'s date range in `table_2` and proceed like this (omitting non-essential columns for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   date_range daterange NOT NULL,
   /* this redundant unique constraint is required
      as target for a foreign key that ensures consistency */
   UNIQUE (date_range, id)
);

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   date_range daterange NOT NULL,
   table_1_id bigint NOT NULL,
   /* this column holds a redundant copy from table_1 */
   table_1_date_range daterange NOT NULL,
   /* this foreign key makes sure that the date range is
      consistent consistent with table_1 */
   FOREIGN KEY (table_1_date_range, table_1_id) REFERENCES table_1 (date_range, id),
   /* this constraint ascertains your desired consition */
   CHECK (date_range <@ table_1_date_range)
);
```

Ugly, isn't it? I'd do without enforcing the constraint like this, the overhead is just too high.

You have to resist the temptation to use a dirty trick like defining a check constraint that calls a function that selects from another table. That is explicitly forbidden and will lead to trouble, see for example [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20091001135900.GE25444%40a-kretschmer.de).

A viable alternative solution is to use a trigger that checks the constraint upon every data modification, but [such triggers always suffer from race conditions](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/), so you'd have to use heavy locking or `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation to make them work reliably.